# Access Vuex before Vue route is resolved

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, vue-router

What do I have:

1. router with auth-required routes and public routes
2. vuex with user's auth state

What do I want: send request to server using `axios` to check user's auth state ***before*** app is loaded (before router is resolved).

`router.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import store from './store'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  ...
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/account',
      name: 'account',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "account" */ './views/Account.vue'),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (store.state.authStatus)
      next()
    else
      next({name: 'home'})
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

export default router
```

`store.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    authStatus: false
  },
  mutations: {
    setAuthStatus(state, authStatus) {
      state.authStatus = authStatus
    }
  }
})

 axios.get(...)
   .then(response => {
     store.commit('setAuthStatus', true)
   })

export default store
```

`main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**My problem**: when I enter `mydomain.com/acount` in browser (app is not loaded before) while being authorized, anyway I got redirect to `home`. And after redirect I see that I'm authorized (I set up some DOM element inside Home component which is shown only for authorized users).

---

I've tried this, didn't helped:

`store.js`:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  ...
  actions: {
    setAuthStatus({commit}) {
      axios.get(...)
        .then(response => {
          commit('setAuthStatus', true)
        })
    }
  }
})
```

`main.js`:

```
store.dispatch('setAuthStatus').then(() => {
  new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
})
```

---

Edit: in `main.js` I tried to go from

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

to

```
new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

and it also didn't helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going around [Vanojx1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52421756/9506712), I solved my question next way.

`store.js`:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    authStatus: axios.get(...).then(response => {
      store.commit('setAuthStatus', true)
    }),
    userAuth: false
  },
  mutations: {
    setAuthStatus(state, authStatus) {
      state.userAuth = authStatus
    }
  }
})
```

`router.js`:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    store.state.authStatus.then(() => {
      //we're getting 200 status code response here, so user is authorized
      //be sure that API you're consuming return correct status code when user is authorized
      next()
    }).catch(() => {
      //we're getting anything but not 200 status code response here, so user is not authorized
      next({name: 'home'})
    })
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In the navigation guard you need something async so save your axios promise in the store as authStatus. When it resolves commit and set the loggedIn status.
In the navigation guard wait for the promise to be resolved and then call the next function to enter the next router.

Store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    /*  EXAMPLE
    authStatus: new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const requestResult = true;
        store.commit("setAuthStatus", requestResult);
        resolve(requestResult);
      }, 1000);
    }),
    */
    authStatus: axios.get(...).then((requestResult) => {
        store.commit("setAuthStatus", requestResult);
    }),
    loggedIn: false
  },
  mutations: {
    setAuthStatus(state, loggedIn) {
      state.loggedIn = loggedIn;
    }
  }
});

export default store;
```

router.js

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    store.state.authStatus.then(loggedIn => {
      if (loggedIn) next();
      else next({ name: "home" });
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Check this solution working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/yqxxl5z2ox)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but where is the place for axios call than?

Comment: `requestResult` is an object by the way (if we talk about axios response)

Comment: Ok then pass true or false to the commit based on the axios response

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably due to the thing that when you enter the url
https://example.com/account

It starts the app and axios performs an asynchronous request to the server.
So maybe you should try making an axios call from within the beforeEach.

By this way you'll have no problem authenticating the user.

The thing is that you cannot make axios synchronous so you have to return a promise with axios in order to achieve the functionality.

Please tell if this came of any help to you.